# How to order a ls output by suffix?

Tags: bash

Having a ls output like

```
GGGG_3.0.3_98/
GGGG_3.0.3_d_100/
GGGG_3.0.3_d_101/
GGGG_3.0.3_d_99/
GGGG_3.0.4_104/
GGGG_3.0.4_105/
GGGG_3.0.4_106/
GGGG_3.0_87/
GGGG_3.0_89/
GGGG_3.0_90/
GGGG_3.0_91/
GGGG_3.0_92/
GGGG_3.0_93/
SSS_2.2.3_01/
SSS_2.2.3_02/
SSS_2.2.3_03/
TTT_2.8.3_29/
```

how to get the elements ordered by suffix?

**Also**, is there any quick command I can use to know that 106 is the last suffix in this example?

Sorry: it wasn't clear that **"the suffix" in the given example is everything following the final underscore.**

Comment: What is the suffix? Everything following the final underscore?

Comment: `ls | sort -n -k3,3 -t_` would do it, except some directories have 3 underscore...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ls ... |awk -F'[_/]' '{f=$(NF-1)>f?$(NF-1):f}END{print f}'
```

will give you `106`

to sort by suffix:

```
ls..|awk -F'[_/]' '{print $(NF-1), $0}'|sort -n|sed 's/.* //'
```

note that

- the `awk|sort|sed` chain is not necessary, awk can do it alone, (by asort/asorti). but it came up first, **dirty** (I know) and quick.
- if the file/dir name has space, it may not work. but it is fixable. e.g. use a invisible char as separator.

Comment: +1 . my idea exactly ^^ : print the sorting field in front, and use sort. You beat me to it! I believe it's `ls -1F` so that there is the trailing `/`. Or something like `ls -d */`.