# UNIX - List files with a given suffix in order of last modification

Tags: unix, ls

I know I can use:

```
for file in *.csv; do echo $file; done
```

to list all the files the current directory with the supplied suffix.

I also know I can use:

```
ls -rt
```

to list all the files in order of when they were modified with the most-recently-modified at the bottom of the list.

I want to combine these two commands to get a list of only files with a particular suffix but sorted by when they were last modified.

Update:
I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17453531/how-to-order-a-ls-output-by-suffix) that looks like it offers a solution but I'm not sure what parts of the solution are applicable to my needs

Comment: what about `ls -rt *.csv`?

Comment: Hey, that works! I had no idea I could do that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xargs` would convert the rows as command line arguments!

```
for file in *.csv; do echo $file; done | xargs ls -rt
```

Also, I would just do `ls -lrt *.csv`